# How to return an error to ValidationSummry in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-validation, asp.net-mvc-controller

I have an idea which I dont know how to implement.
In MVC 3 controller I have an if statement, and I want the controller to return an error message if the if statement fails. And I have a ValidationSummery on that page, so its better if it will catch the error message and present it..

How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the controller you can add an error message by

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string key, string errorMessage);
```

Comment: Cool, that worked. But what it I use excludePropertyErrors=true in ValidationSummery?

Comment: If you don't pass in a key to this function it will work.  The key in this case would be the property name of your model.  So if you do ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Error Message") and excludePropertyErrors = true it will still show up.